# Grails radio for Types

Tags: grails, radio-button

I have a Grails app that I'm trying to do a search based on different fields on an object.  I want to implement a search field with radio buttons to determine which fields get searched.

Example:  Input box has "ABC"
  if box 1 is selected (search title)
  if box 2 is selected (search author)
  if box 1 & 2 are selected (search both title and author and return the item if either match)

so it would look like:

if box 1 (entries = entry.findAllByTitleLike("ABC"))
if box 2 (entries = entry.findAllByAuthorLike("ABC"))

once I get entry I'm ok outputting it, just need to understand how to do multi-selects of radio buttons.

Comment: What do you mean by "multi-selects of radio buttons" ?

Comment: you cannot have multi-selects of radio buttons... checkboxes you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
def entries = entryClass.withCriteria {
  if (box1) {
    like 'title', "ABC"
  }
  if (box2) {
    like 'author', "CDE"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (box1 && box2) {
   entries = entry.findAllByTitleLikeOrAuthorLike("ABC", "ABC")
}
else if (box1) {
   entries = entry.findAllByTitleLike("ABC")
}
else if (box2) {
   entries = entry.findAllByAuthorLike("ABC")
}
else {
   entries = []
}
```